# Siddhi:Multi result per group when using window.cron

Tags: cron, siddhi

Siddhi 3.1.0,
my siddhiql like this:

```
define stream demo(key string, v1 int, v2 int, v3 int);
from demo#window.cron(0/5 * * * * ?)
select key,sum(v1) as v1,sum(v2) as v2,sum(v3) as v3 insert into outputStream
```

I expect to get the result aggregations for the key `key` group, actually I receive one aggregated result per event but not one per group.
I know `timeBatch` can get result per group, but it can't control the output time period.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [GroupBy](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP420/SiddhiQL+Guide+3.1#SiddhiQLGuide3.1-GroupBy) clause.

```
from demo#window.cron(0/5 * * * * ?)
select key,sum(v1) as v1,sum(v2) as v2,sum(v3) as v3 
group by key
insert into outputStream;
```